# Very bad SVG to PNG convertion in PHP

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, png

I am converting a SVG graph to an PNG image in PHP, with ImageMagick. Most of the convertion works but some elements (ex. shadow) are missing and the render of the text is ugly...

The SVG rendered by Chrome :

[image: How the SVG looks like in chrome]

The SVG converted by ImageMagick in PNG

[image: How ImageMagick converts the SVG]

I first added modules to PHP :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra
```

Maybe, there is something better than libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra ?

And in my PHP file :

```
$image = new Imagick();
$svg2 = file_get_contents('roue1.svg');
$image->readImageBlob('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>' . $svg2);
//$image->setImageFormat("png24");
$image->setImageFormat("png");
//$image->resampleimage($width * 10, $height * 10, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
//$image->setresolution($width * 10, $height * 10);
//$image->setimageresolution($width * 10, $height * 10);
//$image->resampleimage($width, $height, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
$image->resizeImage($width, $height, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
$output = $image->getimageblob();
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo $output;
```

As you can see I tried many things but all failed :-(

Here is the full big (sorry) code of my SVG :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <filter id="b" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-opacity=".5" flood-color="#000" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="flood" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" result="composite1"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
      <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" result="offset"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="offset" result="composite2"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="a" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-opacity=".5" flood-color="#000" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="flood" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" result="composite1"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
      <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" result="offset"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="offset" result="composite2"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="c" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-opacity=".5" flood-color="#000" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="flood" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" result="composite1"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
      <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" result="offset"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="offset" result="composite2"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="d" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-opacity=".5" flood-color="#000" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="flood" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" result="composite1"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
      <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" result="offset"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="offset" result="composite2"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="#ccc"/>
  <g fill="#fff" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <path d="M94.286 5.714h11.43v188.57h-11.43z"/>
    <path d="M194.286 94.286v11.43H5.716v-11.43zM85.714 185.714L100 200l14.286-14.286H85.714zM85.714 14.286L100 0l14.286 14.286H85.714z"/>
    <path d="M14.286 114.286L0 100l14.286-14.286v28.572zM185.714 114.286L200 100l-14.286-14.286v28.572z"/>
  </g>
  <g font-weight="bold" font-size="100" font-family="Calibri" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="#fff">
    <text style="line-height:125%;-inkscape-font-specification:'Calibri Bold'" x="56.338" y="273.877" opacity=".5" filter="url(#a)" transform="translate(0 -85.714) scale(.57143)">
      <tspan x="56.338" y="273.877">d</tspan>
    </text>
    <text style="line-height:125%;-inkscape-font-specification:'Calibri Bold'" x="253.506" y="274.707" opacity=".5" filter="url(#b)" transform="translate(0 -85.714) scale(.57143)">
      <tspan x="253.506" y="274.707">i</tspan>
    </text>
    <text style="line-height:125%;-inkscape-font-specification:'Sans Bold'" x="246.436" y="423.877" opacity=".5" filter="url(#c)" transform="translate(0 -85.714) scale(.57143)">
      <tspan x="246.436" y="423.877">s</tspan>
    </text>
    <text style="line-height:125%;-inkscape-font-specification:'Sans Bold'" x="60.484" y="423.926" opacity=".5" filter="url(#d)" transform="translate(0 -85.714) scale(.57143)">
      <tspan x="60.484" y="423.926">c</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <path fill="#0074d9" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M85 100h15v15H85z"/>
  <path fill="#2ecc40" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M100 100h25v25h-25z"/>
  <path fill="#ffdc00" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M100 65h35v35h-35z"/>
  <path fill="#ff4136" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M55 55h45v45H55z"/>
  <path d="M55 55l80 10-10 60-40-10z" opacity=".5" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="2"/>
  <rect width="55" height="20" x="143" y="177" ry="5.227" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.022"/>
  <path fill="#fff" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".587" d="M148 182h10v10h-10z"/>
  <text style="line-height:125%;-inkscape-font-specification:'Sans Bold'" x="161" y="189.899" font-weight="bold" font-size="9" font-family="Verdana" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0">
    <tspan x="161.38" y="189.899" font-size="8">Adapté</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: I finally installed inskape (apt-get install inskape) and I use it as external command from php. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

A number of thoughts...

**Density/Resolution**

If you want to set the resolution/density, you need to set it **before** you load the image, i.e. before ImageMagick rasterises the vectors into a bitmap. Afterwards it is too late. So,

```
convert -density 288 image.svg image.png
```

will work, whereas this will not

```
convert image.svg -density 288 image.png
```

Same in PHP, with:

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->setImageResolution(288,288);
$imagick->readImageBlob();
```

**Inkscape fonts**

I don't think ImageMagick is going to understand Inkscape fonts, so you may be advised to change that by editing the SVG file (maybe on the fly), or set a fallback font before you load the SVG:

```
convert -density 288 -font FALLBACK image.svg image.png
```

**Shadows**

Not too sure what is going on with shadows, but check which delegate ImageMagick is using and see if you can use the `rsvg` one which generally does a better job.

```
identify -list delegate | grep svg
```

Comment: phpinfp says I'm using ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2015-01-06. dentify -list delegate | grep svg says svg => "rsvg-convert" -o "%o" "%i" but I'm not sure that php5-imagick + libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra has something to do with this command.

Comment: I do not find how to do the density first in PHP :-(

Comment: +1 Mark. I don't believe all those filters have been implemented in `MSVG`, but they seem to be present in [`rsvg`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/librsvg/tree/rsvg-filter.c?id=40af93e6eb1c94b90c3b9a0b87e0840e126bb8df)